# Проблема синхронизации потоков в Embarcadero Builder C++

Tags: c++, синхронизация, radstudio

Пишу оконное приложение на Embarcadero C++ Builder XE7, ОС Windows 7.
В нем при запуске главной формы создается, но сразу не запускается поток.

```
SenderThread *MySendTestThread = new SenderThread(true);
MySendTestThread->FreeOnTerminate = true;
MySendTestThread->Priority = tpHighest;
```

Далее в основной программе я создаю класс MyInterTest и вызываю его функцию, в которой
запускается поток MySendTestThread, и дальше бесконечный цикл.

```
.......
NotEnd = true;
while (NotEnd)
{
    // Какие-то действия
}
.......
```

Предполагается, что по завершении работы функции SenderThread::Execute() переменная NotEnd будет установлена в false,
и вышеописанный цикл закончится.

```
void __fastcall SenderThread::Execute()
{
    // Какие-то действия        
    TestForm->MyInterTest->NotEnd = false;
}
```

Но выходит, что поток MySendTestThread ждет завершения работы основной программы, а только потом выполняется сам.
Может у кого есть варианты, почему так может быть?

Comment: В доке нету `SenderThread`

Comment: Это мой класс - потомок абстрактного класса TThread.

Comment: `SecondProcess->Resume(); // now run the thread` из доки http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_TThread_Create.html

Comment: > Most methods that access an object and update a form must only be called from within the main thread or use a synchronization object such as TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer.